# Thread Safety with less locking

Tags: c#, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Threading & Blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810549/c-sharp-threading-blocking)

I am trying to effectively determine which approach is better:

Currently, I have a singleton instance that exposes entities that are loaded in lazy load fashion. I have listed three approaches which each of which has some advantages. The first approach relies solely on double lock pattern to ensure thread safety. The second approach doesn't use locking but it has the potential of double Load in case of a race. The third approach really uses a solution that I am becoming very fond of. (System.Lazy).

For some reason, I feel there is something wrong with the second approach (System.Thread.InterLocked), yet i can't pin point it. Is there a reason to favor one approach over the other? I did cover this in a previous post where I felt the third option is the way to go from now on.

I stripped the code to the barebones to be able explain the design.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TPLDemo
{
  public class SomeEntity
  {
  }

  public class MultiThreadedManager
  {
    private static readonly System.Lazy<MultiThreadedManager> instance = new Lazy<MultiThreadedManager>(() => { return new MultiThreadedManager(); });
    private readonly object _syncRoot = new object();
    private List<SomeEntity> _inMemoryEntities = null;
    private List<SomeEntity> _inMemoryEntitiesUsingLockFreeApproach = null;
    private System.Lazy<List<SomeEntity>> _inMemoryUsingLazy = new Lazy<List<SomeEntity>>(() => { return MultiThreadedManager.Instance.LoadFromSomewhere(); });

    public static MultiThreadedManager Instance
    {
      get { return instance.Value; }
    }


    public IEnumerable<SomeEntity> LazyEntities
    {
      get
      {
        return _inMemoryUsingLazy.Value;
      }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SomeEntity> LocklessEntities
    {
      get
      {
        if (_inMemoryEntitiesUsingLockFreeApproach == null)
        {
          do
          {
          // Is it possible multiple threads hit this at the same time?
          } while (System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange<List<SomeEntity>>(ref                _inMemoryEntitiesUsingLockFreeApproach, this.LoadFromSomewhere(), null) != null);
        }

        return _inMemoryEntitiesUsingLockFreeApproach;
      }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This is thread safe but it involved some locking. 
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<SomeEntity> Entities
    {
      get
      {
        if (_inMemoryEntities == null)
        {
          lock (_syncRoot)
          {
            if (_inMemoryEntities == null)
            {
              List<SomeEntity> list = this.LoadFromSomewhere();
              _inMemoryEntities = list;
            }
          }
        }

        return _inMemoryEntities;
      }
    }

    private List<SomeEntity> LoadFromSomewhere()
    {
      return new List<SomeEntity>();
    }

    public void ReloadEntities()
    {
      // This is sufficient becasue any subsequent call will reload them safely. 
      _inMemoryEntities = null;

      // This is sufficient becasue any subsequent call will reload them safely. 
      _inMemoryEntitiesUsingLockFreeApproach = null;

      // This is necessary becasue _inMemoryUsingLazy.Value is readonly.
      _inMemoryUsingLazy = new Lazy<List<SomeEntity>>(() => { return MultiThreadedManager.Instance.LoadFromSomewhere(); });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't the answer in your first post (use `System.Lazy<T>`, that's what it's for) good enough?

Answer (score 0):

The third option (`Lazy`) allows you to configure how it should behave. You can make it behave like (1) or like (2).

In any case, once it is loaded it does not need to lock or interlock internally to hand you back the loaded `Value`.

So by all means go for `System.Lazy`.

There is one nasty thing though: If the factory function fails, the exception is stored and thrown everytime the `Value` property is accessed. This means that this `Lazy` instance is not ruined. You cannot ever retry. This means that a transient failure (network error, ...) might permanently take down your application until it is manually restarted.

If have complained about this on MS Connect but it is by design.

My solution was to write my own `Lazy`. It's not hard.